# Gitlab CI pipeline SonarQube msbuild error ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null

Tags: msbuild, gitlab-ci, sonarqube-scan

Is anyone familiar with this error and how to solve it? I'm using Sonarqube Scanner 2.3.1 and msbuild 12.0. The project is 4.5 framework.

```
Time Elapsed 00:00:39.12
$ SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end
SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.3.1
Default properties file was found at C:\SonarQube\bin\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Loading analysis properties from C:\SonarQube\bin\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
sonar.verbose=true was specified - setting the log verbosity to 'Debug'
Post-processing started.
11:00:26.108  Using environment variables to determine the download directory...
11:00:26.188  11:00:26.188  sonar.verbose=true was specified - setting the log verbosity to 'Debug'
11:00:26.191  Loading the SonarQube analysis config from F:\Gitlab-Runner\builds\1d3a7e33\1\folder\folder\folder\.sonarqube\conf\SonarQubeAnalysisConfig.xml
11:00:26.191  Not running under TeamBuild
11:00:26.191  Analysis base directory: F:\Gitlab-Runner\builds\1d3a7e33\1\folder\folder\folder\.sonarqube
Build directory: 
Bin directory: F:\Gitlab-Runner\builds\1d3a7e33\1\folder\folder\folder\.sonarqube\bin
Config directory: F:\Gitlab-Runner\builds\1d3a7e33\1\folder\folder\folder\.sonarqube\conf
Output directory: F:\Gitlab-Runner\builds\1d3a7e33\1\folder\folder\folder\.sonarqube\out
Config file: F:\Gitlab-Runner\builds\1d3a7e33\1\folder\folder\folder\.sonarqube\conf\SonarQubeAnalysisConfig.xml
Generating SonarQube project properties file to F:\Gitlab-Runner\builds\1d3a7e33\1\folder\folder\folder\.sonarqube\out\sonar-project.properties

Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
   at SonarQube.Common.ListPropertiesProvider.TryGetProperty(String key, Property& property)
   at SonarQube.Common.AggregatePropertiesProvider.TryGetProperty(String key, Property& property)
   at SonarQube.Common.AggregatePropertiesProvider.GetAllProperties()
   at SonarScanner.Shim.PropertiesFileGenerator.GetAnalysisProperties(AnalysisConfig config)
   at SonarScanner.Shim.PropertiesFileGenerator.GenerateFile(AnalysisConfig config, ILogger logger, IRoslynV1SarifFixer fixer)
   at SonarScanner.Shim.SonarScannerWrapper.Execute(AnalysisConfig config, IEnumerable`1 userCmdLineArguments, ILogger logger)
   at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PostProcessor.MSBuildPostProcessor.InvokeSonarScanner(IAnalysisPropertyProvider cmdLineArgs, AnalysisConfig config)
   at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PostProcessor.MSBuildPostProcessor.Execute(String[] args, AnalysisConfig config, ITeamBuildSettings settings)
   at SonarQube.Bootstrapper.BootstrapperClass.PostProcess()
   at SonarQube.Bootstrapper.BootstrapperClass.Execute()
   at SonarQube.Bootstrapper.Program.Execute(String[] args, ILogger logger)
   at SonarQube.Bootstrapper.Program.Main(String[] args)
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 3762504530
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the property called sonar.analysis.mode being set equal to "issues".

issues mode should never be used manually as it is used only by tools.
set your sonar.analysis.mode=[preview/publish] 
 (publish is default so you don't have to set the property at all if that's what you want.)